# How to read all href link in html "<a>" tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get all href link values using javascript. I have this code,

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="download-link" id="download_link" href="%file_url%">Download</a>
</div>
</body>
```

It shows like this

```
<a class="download-link" href="http://mysite.com/download/myfiles/file1.pdf">Download</a>
<a class="download-link" href="http://mysite.com/download/myfiles/file2.docx">Download</a>
<a class="download-link" href="http://mysite.com/download/myfiles/file3.zip">Download</a>
<a class="download-link" href="http://mysite.com/download/myfiles/file4.html">Download</a>
```

but if I used a native javascript like on the code below, only the first item is shown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var url = document.getElementById("download_link").href;
var ext = url.split('.').pop();
alert(ext);
}
</script>
```

Why I'm getting only one output when I used a javascript to display the items? I tested it using their file extensions since I splitted the files. Any Idea What is missing on the javascript? I just want to continuously display(Alert) the items. My problem is, It only display the first item.

Comment: You're using `getElementById` (**id**), but `a`s have `class` attribute. Use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 7):

You can get a `NodeList` of all `a` elements using [`document.getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094). That list has a `length`, and you can index into it with `[]`. E.g.:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    // Do something with links[i].href
}
```

On [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), if you wanted to limit that further (for instance, only links with the `download-link` class on them), you can use `querySelectorAll`, which accepts a CSS selector:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.download-link');
// ...and then use it the same way as above
```

Answer (score 1):

You're fetching only one element with a specific ID. You need to get all anchor elements

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var url = anchors[i].href;
        alert(url.split('.').pop());
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` returns the object for a single unique element identified by an`id` attribute. You are looking to get all the objects that share a common`class`and for that you'll need something like`document.getElementsByTagName()`.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` retrieves only one object as there can be only one object with a given `id`. But none of those have ids to begin with.

You can use `getElementsByTagName('a')` as already suggested, but that would retrieve a list of all `a` tags in the page and aparently that is not what you really want.

I guess you should go with the third option `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
var objs = document.getElementsByClassName('download-link');
var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; ++i)
    links[i] = objs[i].href;

alert(links.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the array method **map** on the document.links collection.

The String value of a link element its url.

```
var hrefs= [].map.call(document.links,String);
alert(hrefs.join('\n'));
```